# Incrementing variables in liquid without outputting them

Tags: shopify, liquid

I am doing a for loop in shopify, I need to increment a variable.

However, when I do

```
{% increment variable %}
```

besides incrementing it, it shows the output on the screen!

I can't believe it. Is there a way to avoid this?

Thank you

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is by design, at it allows you to increment and display a variable at the same time. See [the documentation](http://shopify.github.io/liquid/tags/variable/#increment).

`assign` only allows you to assign *new* variables (and not modify existing ones), so aside from creating a new tag, the easiest way is to use use `capture` to capture the output:

```
{% capture _ %}{% increment variable %}{% endcapture %}
```

That being said, perhaps it's time to re-consider why exactly you're doing this? Note that you already have `forloop.index` and `forloop.index0` available for the loop index (once again, [see the documentation](https://docs.shopify.com/themes/liquid/objects/for-loops)).

Comment: could you please have a look at the similar issue posted here @ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69415986/shopify-liquid-add-a-new-row-based-on-a-condition

Comment: The "re-consider" comment saved me a real headaches doing something similar.

Answer (score 31):

If you are using a different logic for incrementing the value than `forloop.index`, you can use the [`plus` filter](https://shopify.dev/docs/themes/liquid/reference/filters/math-filters#plus) to increment the variable:

```
{% assign variable = 0 %}
{% for … %}
  {% assign variable = variable | plus: 1 %}
{% endfor %}
```

I can also recommend that you have a look at the [cheat sheet for Shopify](http://cheat.markdunkley.com/).